How choose the files with dates greater than a specific date using python pandas?
Here are the files in the folder below:
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240901.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240902.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240903.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240904.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240905.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240906.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240907.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240908.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240909.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240910.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240911.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240912.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240913.csv

Here is the code I use to select a file only and it will only read that file,
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from numpy import *
import glob
import os
import os.path
import duckdb

_path = r'C:\temporary_location\\'

_frame = []

for loc in glob.glob(_path + '*.csv'):
    if "20240905" in loc:
        print('Loading', loc)
        data = pd.read_csv(loc, low_memory=False)

How do I use the same code above to choose the files with dates greater than a specific date?
For example:
for loc in glob.glob(_path + '*.csv'):
    if 20240905 > loc:
        print('Loading', loc)
        data = pd.read_csv(loc, low_memory=False)

The code should print below files.
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240906.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240907.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240908.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240909.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240910.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240911.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240912.csv
C:\temporary_location\file_name_20240913.csv


You might use pandas.to_datetime function following way
import glob
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"filename": glob.glob("file_name_*.csv")})
df["when"] = pd.to_datetime(df.filename, format="%Y%m%d", exact=False)
files_after_2024_09_10 = df[df.when > "2024-09-10"].filename
for fname in files_after_2024_09_10:
    print(fname)

gives output
file_name_20240912.csv
file_name_20240911.csv
file_name_20240913.csv

Observe that you should inform pd.to_datetime about format used and that it should for it somewhere in string by passing exact=False. Note: for brevity sake I show working with files in current working directory, whole path will be present if you change glob.glob's argument.

Thank you.  I prefer to do this instead, files_after_2024_09_10 = (df[df.when > "2024-09-10"].when).tolist() will print dates in array: filterdate = ['2024-09-11', '2024-09-12', '2024-09-13']. This result will be used in a for loop: for example..
for loc in glob.glob(_path + '*.csv'):
for x in filterdate:
if x in loc:
print('Loading', loc)
data = pd.read_csv(loc, low_memory=False)

Try getting the last 8 digits excluding .csv
if int(loc[-12:-4]) > 20240905:


Can loc use on pathlike string?

@TCO Can't convert to string?
